# click on a image link with Capybara

Tags: xpath, rspec-rails

I am trying to click on a image link with a Capybara / Rspec test. I am having very little success at the moment.

I am trying to select the link with href "/post/3", (knowing that they are other links before).  I have tried many combinations of xpath without success.  The only combination working was

```
page.first(:xpath, //a).click
```

however when I have changed the file and added more links above my Capybara test is broken.

```
   <div class='row'>
  <a href="/posts/3"><img id="imagen3" src="/system/posts/images/000/000/003/original/frankie-mannings-102nd-birthday-5160522641047552-hp.gif?1464448829" alt="Frankie mannings 102nd birthday 5160522641047552 hp" /></a>
  <p>caption</p>
</div>
```

How can I select that link, and click it?

Answer (score 1):

```html
//a[contains(@href, 'posts/3')]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.   Yes that I have tried again with no success, (please note that  your ’ char after 3 should be ', but even correcting that does not work..)

Answer (score 0):

ok I got it:
`find(:xpath, "//a[contains(@href,'posts/3}')]").click`